# Adding new data to the end of a table using power query

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery, vba

I've got my query that pulls data from sql server 2012 into excel using power query. However, when I change the date range in my query I'd like to pull the new data into my table and store it below the previously pulled data without deleting it. So far all I've found is the refresh button, which will rerun my query with the new dates but replace the old. Is there a way to accomplish this? I'm using it to build an automated QA testing program that will compare this period to last. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, you might want to consider updating your question with more specifics (if you want to keep the prior update then I immediately wonder how many "prior" updates you want to keep / maybe even a history / what differs between the updates / could it be solved with a `UNION ALL` sql) and what you have tried / researched thus far to complete the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like incremental load. If your table doesn't exceed 1,1 Mio rows, you can use the technique described here: http://www.thebiccountant.com/2016/02/09/how-to-create-a-load-history-or-load-log-in-power-query-or-power-bi/